# Print specific values in python dataframe for which lambda is applied

Tags: python, json, dataframe, lambda

I have some code which reads a json file and applies a lambda that removes values.
Code -

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('filename.json',dtype='int64')
data = data[data['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x == None or (x.isnumeric() and len(x) <= 2))]
```

The last statements filter outs records from dataframe where anything other than numbers having length 2 is in ColumnA (please correct if I'm wrong).

Objective - Before applying the lambda, I want to print the record from dataframe, so that i can know what kind of values are getting removed.

P.S. I am new to python and working on some predesigned code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is filtering a DataFrame based on the values. Doing this involves two steps:

1. Creating a boolean array of True/False for those that you want/don't want
2. Indexing the original DataFrame that boolean array to filter the select only the values that you want.

In your code, you are doing both steps at once (and that's perfectly fine). But if you want to look at the values, it might be helpful to get the boolean array and look at that one.

```py
data = data[data['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x == None or (x.isnumeric() and len(x) <= 2))]

# can become

# step 1
my_values = data['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x == None or (x.isnumeric() and len(x) <= 2))

# step2
data = data[my_values]

# you can use my_values to inspect what is happening
print(my_values)  # this will be a series of just True/False
print(data[my_values]) # this will print the kept values
print(data[~my_values]) # this will print the removed values
```